# Reading Attributes from Attributed Relationship Class ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

I have an M-N relationship class with attributes. I am listening to the [**`IRelationshipClassEvents.OnCreate Event`**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000072r000000) event to see if any new relations are created. How can I read these attributes from an `IRelationship`?

```
private void m_editEvents_OnCreateRelation(IRelationship rel)
{
    //how to get the attribute here?
}
```

Comment: Did you try casting to IRow or IRowBuffer and looking at the values?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall - you are right..it gets me the attributes..if you can copy the comment to an answer, i will close it as an answer..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to implementing the `IRelationship` interface, the [attributedrelationship coclass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000008000000) also implements `IRow` and `IRowBuffer`.  This means that you should be able to cast `rel` to one of these interfaces and access the attributes.